# What is the meaning of "Inferno"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-difference

In Portuguese (Brazil) **Inferno** means *Hell*, but I have seen this word in another context, like in games… but I think it does not have the same definition. Is **Inferno** the same as *Hell*?

Comment: That's the general connotation, yes, after Dante's famous work *Inferno*. But it originally simply meant *furnace*, and sometimes in English it is used devoid of any religious or literary overtones: simply *a very hot place*, a *burning place*.

Comment: I live in the US, and **Inferno** simply means a large fire, or a large place on fire - it doesn't mean hell. It can also be used to mean "chaos", as in "her thoughts became an inferno", meaning "her thoughts became chaotic"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infernus (Latin) meant *underground, of the lower regions*, from [*inferus/infra*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1007339), meaning below (as in *inferior*/infrastructure*.)

Inferno is Italian, from Late Latin infernalis "of the lower regions,"
so originally it referred to the underworld. Since Catholicism emphasized the fiery nature of Hell, inferno came to mean hell, and this use was immortalized by Dante Alighieri in his famous poem *The Divine Comedy* (written 1308 -1320) (part I: Inferno).

Modern usage of inferno is to connote a particularly hot or dangerous fire, or a place of great human suffering (the final circle of hell is a frozen lake):

> of or pertaining to or characteristic of a very uncontrolled and intense fire; a place or condition suggestive of hell, especially with respect to human suffering or death; a place or region that resembles hell, esp. in intense heat. -[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inferno)
>
> > "The fire on Thursday afternoon began with an explosion at 121 Second Avenue and grew to an inferno engulfing four neighboring buildings." - NYT